# Cant POST into .NET Core Web API from Angular without Anonymous Authentication

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, http-post

I'm working in Angular 9 along with .NET core Web API 3.1 with EF.

I am relying to AD based authorization using Integrated Windows Authentication which is crucial because I need to get few groups where the user belongs to.

Everything working until I require a POST method. When I tried to do a POST, it triggering a CORS error. So as an interim solution I enabled Anonymous Authentication along with Windows Authentication. Then I am able to do POST. But in that case I am not getting user details.

For example when anonymous authentication enabled **User.Identity.name** is null

So please help to overcome this issue. I need both User Details as well as POST methods

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by just using Authorize attribute to the controllers which require User Details from HTTPCONTEXT

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
[Authorize]
public class myChangeController :ControllerBase
{
....
....
}
```

So both Anonymous and Windows authentication as well enabled